# ActivityGroup inside TabHost does not show content after first run

Tags: android, back, activitygroup

I have issue with ActivityGroup. My app has 4 tabs, 2 of which has ActivityGroup and 2 more simple activity. The problem is that after first run of app content is shown properly, and when leave app through back button and return, tabs with activity group dont shown any content, including menus. While tabs with simple activity work properly.
D'you have any ideas?

---

Ok, some sort of code) 
Setting this tab:

```
private TabSpec getFrontPageTab() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityGroupHome.class);
        return tabHost
                .newTabSpec("home")
                .setIndicator(
                        getTabView(R.drawable.tabbar_home, "str_home"))
                .setContent(intent);

    }
```

ActivityGroupHome:

```
public class ActivityGroupHome extends ActivityGroupBase {

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityUtils activityUtils = ActivityUtils.getInstance(this);

    activityUtils.addActivityGroup("Home", this);
    activityUtils.startHomeActivity("Home");

} 

}
```

Methods from ActivityUtils:

```
public void startHomeActivity(String activityGroupName) {

    if (activityGroupName != null) {

        startHomeActivityForActivityGroup(activityGroupName);

    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AsyncMainActivity.class);
        // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }

}

private void startHomeActivityForActivityGroup(String activityGroupName) {

    ActivityGroupListItem activityGroupItem = activityGroups
            .findGroupByName(activityGroupName);

    if (activityGroupItem != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(activityGroupItem.activityGroup,
                AsyncMainActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(ACTIVITY_GROUP_NAME, activityGroupItem.name);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        View view = activityGroupItem.activityGroup
                .getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Home", intent)
                .getDecorView();
        activityGroupItem.activityGroup.setContentView(view);
        activityGroupItem.stack.add("Home");

    }

}
```

Comment: Add some code stuff to lets us know what you have tried.

Comment: This is such situation, in which I just dont know what code to show you. App is very huge, ActivityGroup is implemented in a standard way, but after first destroying dont show any content. Under debug I see that it goes through onCreate with null savedInstanceState in second run, all threads are started, but no UI content. Any ideas?